# How to get URL query string in API route in Next.js?

Tags: node.js, next.js

I have a constant that uses the request query to pull into my API the name and town values of the URL parameters.

This works great. What I can't work out, I've looked at a number of articles but I want to return the full set of parameters from the URL, either as an array or a string. If it includes the URL path it's no problem, ideally just the parameters ampersand separated or any other way.

I need to do so as this API captures a set of question responses that may change over time, and I need the flexibility to loop over all the answers returned irrelevant if its 10 or 100.

```js
export default async function (req, res) {
    const {
        query: name ,
        query: town ,
    } = req
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but don't you have access to `req.url`, which contains the full URL including the query params?

Comment: Thanks Juliomalves, I was looking for a reference of the properties on req, but all I found was numerous examples not the properties... if you post it, I'll mark it as the anwser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access the query params as a string from `req.url` which contains the full URL including the query params.

```js
export default async function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.url) // Logs: '/api/info?name=john&town=london'
}
```

For more details on the `req` object check [Node.js official documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage).

---

Alternatively, you can also get the query params as an object from the `req.query` object, which you can manipulate however you like.

```js
export default async function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.query) // Logs: { name: 'john', town: 'london' }
}
```